# Closed form for integer series from enumerative geometry problem?

Tags: integer-sequences, enumerative-geometry

Is there a closed form for the following integer sequence:

$$
1,6,145,8806,830622,100317140,14342519633,2325250316950,...
$$

This is the degree of the $2n$-th power of the Schubert class $\sigma_{2,2}$ for a $2\times 2$-box on the Grassmannian $Gr(4,2n+4)$, for $n=1,2,....$ Alternatively, it is the number of projective 3-planes intersecting $2n$ general projective $(2n-1)$-dimensional subspaces in $\mathbb{P}^{2n+3}$ in a line. The enumerative problem was discussed in a paper of Finashin and Kharlamov:

- S. Finashin and V. Kharlamov. Abundance of 3-planes in real projective hypersurfaces. Arnold Math. J. 1 (2015), Page 171-199. [(link to paper on arXiv)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3871)

There are some integral formulas and growth estimates in that paper, but not really a closed formula (sorry, but integral expressions don't count for me). I also checked, but OEIS doesn't seem to know the series (or slight variations of it).

I would also be interested in combinatorial interpretations of the numbers. For reasons discussed in the paper of Finashin and Kharlamov, there are some (though weak) relations to Catalan numbers.